# Cannot access Internet after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet, thinkpad

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 a couple of days ago via internet using "sudo apt-get upgrade".

After the upgrade, both my wired connection and wireless connection stopped talking to the internet when using Firefox or Chrome.

I do not have any problem exchanging files with another PC (running Ubuntu 10.04) use Filezilla within the same network and am able to use Firefox to log into my router to check configuration.

What is so strange was the system appeared to be able to reach out to internet to download files when I run "sudo apt-get update".

I am really baffled by this. Any help to get me back my internet access for both wired/wireless connections would be appreciated.

Here's some information about my settings (wireless intentionally disabled when this snapshot is taken):

```
The unit is a ThinkPad T60.
ifconfig:
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:58:7d:17:04  
      inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:58ff:fe7d:1704/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:50700 (50.7 KB)  TX bytes:24254 (24.2 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:ee000000-ee020000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:57669 (57.6 KB)  TX bytes:57669 (57.6 KB)

sudo lshw -C network:
*-network               
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: eth0
      version: 00
      serial: 00:15:58:7d:17:04
      size: 100Mbit/s
      capacity: 1Gbit/s
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt    10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-1 ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
      resources: irq:45 memory:ee000000-ee01ffff ioport:3000(size=32)
 *-network DISABLED
      description: Wireless interface
      product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
      logical name: wlan0
      version: 02
      serial: 00:18:de:b8:b1:c2
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
      resources: irq:47 memory:edf00000-edf00fff


route -n  (revised using dhcp):
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. May I ask, whether you're able to ping website through the terminal.. Also, please post the output for `route -n` once connected either through LAN or WLAN. :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I cannot ping any website through Network tool or terminal. Does that mean a dns problem?

Comment: Here's the output from 'route -n' (I updated the original thread in the code box).

Comment: The route is based on the current setting (with static IP as recommended by @begueradj)

Comment: @AzkerM, please note I updated the above `route -n` after switching back to use dhcp. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, change `managed=false` to `managed=true`.
2. From the top-right corner select *Edit Connections*, and add a new connection. Specify your ip address, netmask, gateway, and the DNS server being 8.8.8.8.
3. Then run: `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: On Xbuntu after an upgrade I had the same issue: no network, kernel mod loaded, interfaces defined in `ifconfig` and `lshw network`, but nothing worked. I finally did steps 1 and 3 above and the network worked for me after that.

Answer (score 2):

Edit correctly the following files:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/hosts
```

In `/etc/network/interfaces` specify these information:

```
 auto ethX
    iface ethX inet static

    address
    netmask
    broadcast
    dns-nameserver
    gateway
```

ethX: X can be 0,1, 2 ... depending on the network interface you are using.
But in your case it is `eth0`

In `/etc/resolv.conf` specify these information:

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
```

(you can add a new nameserver address on a new line)

In `/etc/hosts` add your username and address on the 3rd line as follows:

```
  yourUsername yourIPaddress
```

After you saved the 3 files, run this command:

```
sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I were to define eth0 or wlan0 (my wireless connection) to use only DHCP, do I need to define dns-nameserver, broadcast and gateway? Also, I think the last command may contain a typo, should be: "sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0" right?

Comment: No, if you are using DHCP it will take care of the settings. Sorry, you are right, I had to write INTERFACE in the above commande which I just edited.

Comment: How do I extract a syslog to post here so that you can help in diagnose what is happening to the internet access?

Comment: You can run this command: cat /var/log/syslog

Comment: Thanks. But it is a pretty large file. Do you want me to post the file in a link? or is there any particular part of the log that can help in this diagnosis? Please advise.

Comment: of course it is a large file. But you can post the data that interest you starting from a given time (date/hour)

Comment: Please advice how to send you the log file.

Comment: Do not send the whole file: just copy/past the date within it starting from yesterday (for example). Run this: sudo gedit /var/log/syslog . Once the file is open, just scroll down and copy/past to here the last lines of it starting from yesterday.

Comment: Even if you are using DHCP, please edit this file /etc/hosts as I highlited above.

Comment: Its not necessary to edit host files I assume. To obtain the latest tail of the log you may either use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to see live log while disconnecting and reconnecting the networks or use `tail -f /var/log/syslog > syslog.txt` to simply capture it to a file.\

Comment: OK. You can find the syslog from today [here]:(http://www.wepaste.com/user272772/)

Answer (score 1):

After several tinkering of the settings with helps from various readers here, the situation had not been improved.

So, I eventually backed up all the important files and did a full install of 14.04.
Now the system is capable of getting to the internet and internal networks. There are, however, a few "glitches" in 14.04 gnome comparing to 13.10. But at least I can use my system again.

Thank you for those who lent a helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my WiFi connection , I tried to edit Newtworkmanager.conf
but didn't work for me .

I went to edit connection and deleted my Wifi connection 
Then added it again and entered the password ...

and It fortunately work :)

Comment: According to the question the issue exists with the wired network connection as well, so any WiFi-related fixes are not going to work.

Comment: sorry, I thought he was talking about Wifi ,I didn't notice "the wired" connection.
Apologies