# Not able to Connect Internet even after configuring Ethernet Interfaces in Ubuntu 14,10

Tags: internet, 14.10

I am new to Ubuntu 14.10, I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 and  configured the
    Ethernet interfaces just like below with static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
    And i also added DNS Server in `/etc/reslov.conf` file.

But when i googled something, it gives error like "*Server not found , Check your Internet Connection*".

---

**Ethernet Interface Configuration in /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.X.X.X
    gateway 10.X.X.X
    netmask 255.X.X.X

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.X.X.X
    gateway 192.X.X.X
    netmask 255.X.X.X
```

---

**DNS Server Configuration in /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 10.X.X.X
```

Comment: are those interfaces by default or did you set them yourself ?

Comment: @begueradj I did these configurations manually

Comment: Why did you made it static?

Comment: @Thushi I need this address at several places. So , I don't want to look it into ifconfig result everytime

Comment: Ok Which interface is connected to internet?

Comment: @Thushi interface---eth0

Comment: @user3386914 try to ping 8.8.8.8 and ping [your gateway] - what are the results? And also are you 100% sure you've set the correct values? (Did they work previously?)

Comment: @user300458.. For both(dns and gateway), when i ping, I am getting "Destination host is not reachable"

And previously, i was working on ubuntu 12.04 and these values was fine at that time.

Comment: what if you follow my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453401/cannot-access-internet-after-14-04-upgrade/453413#453413) ?

Comment: @begueradj When i executed this "sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0", it says that network-interface is not recognized service, but I think, if we run this "service network-manager restart" command,then we don't need to execute your command to restart networking.Correct me if i wrong?

One more thing,If we had already configured DNS server in resolv.conf, then we don't need to do it inside /etc/network/interfaces. Please correct if i wrong?

Comment: good, write the solution you found as answer so that further users who have the same problem as yours will know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Finally all is good. Actually i am using two interface card, 
previously i configured these two in wrong way, i did ones setting to others and      
others setting to ones. When i exchange the cables for these two interfaces, i found that it is working fine.
```

---

**Thanks** to @begueradj, @Thushi, @user3386914 for your comments